# Prove that $T^{4} -12T^{2} +64$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[T]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, irreducible-polynomials

Is the following correct?

I choose $3$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}$.

If $g=(1+(3))T^{4} - (12 + (3))T^{2} + (64 + (3)) \in \mathbb{Z[T]}/(3)$ is irreducible, then $f=T^{4} -12T^{2} +64 \in \mathbb{Z}[T]$ is irreducible.

$g=(1+(3))T^{4} - (12 + (3))T^{2} + (64 + (3))=(1+(3))T^{4} + (1+ (3)) \in \mathbb{Z[T]}/(3)$

Now $g$ is reducible if there is an $x \in \mathbb{Z}/(3)$ such that $x^{4} + 1=0$. That implies $x^{4} = 2 \in \mathbb{Z}/(3)$. But that element doesn't exist. Hence $f \in \mathbb{Z[T]}$ is irreducible. And  $f \in \mathbb{Q[T]}$ is also irreducible.

Comment: Your last two lines are wrong (and your first "irreducible" there seems to have been meant to be "reducible"). You seem to believe that if a polynomial doesn't have a root over some field then it is irreducible over that field, but this only works for polynomials of degree $\;\le 3\;$ .

Comment: To see your error consider the following calculation over $\Bbb{Z}/(3)$:
$$T^4+1=T^4-3T^2+1=(T^4-2T^2+1)-T^2=(T^2-1)^2-T^2=(T^2-T-1)(T^2+T-1).$$

Comment: Thank you both for showing me my mistake.